# Linearization of External System Dynamics in VectorSystem DoCalcVectorOutput Method

Tags: python, drake

I am attempting to implement a custom linear MPC controller class in Drake, which inherits from the VectorSystem base class. This controller is supposed to linearize the dynamics of a given plant at its current operating point, and then perform a trajectory optimization.

I have defined the MPC controller class here.

```
class MpcController(VectorSystem):

def __init__(self, quadrotor_plant, init_state, target_state, time_horizon, max_time_samples, thrust_limit, obstacle_list):
    # define this system as having 12 inputs and 4 outputs
    VectorSystem.__init__(self, 12, 4)
    self.quadrotor_plant = quadrotor_plant
    self.init_state = init_state
    self.target_state = target_state
    self.time_horizon = time_horizon
    self.max_time_samples = max_time_samples
    self.thrust_limit = thrust_limit
    self.obstacle_list = obstacle_list
    self.current_step = 0

def DoCalcVectorOutput(self, context, inp, state, output):

    quadrotor_context = self.quadrotor_plant.CreateDefaultContext()


    # print("DoCalcVectorOutput quad input value", quad_input_port.HasValue(quadrotor_context))

    # input into the controller is the state of the quadrotor
    # set the context equal to the current state
    quadrotor_context.SetContinuousState(inp)
    current_state = inp

    print(f"cur_quad_state = {current_state}")
    print(f"quadrotor current input = {output}")

    ##################
    # Linearize system dynamics - Take first order taylor series expansions of system
    # around the operating point defined by quadrotor context
    ##################
    eq_check_tolerance = 10e6 # we do not need to be at an equilibrium point
    linear_quadrotor = Linearize(self.quadrotor_plant, quadrotor_context, \
    equilibrium_check_tolerance = eq_check_tolerance )
```

I have setup my simulation like so:

```
# define the quadrotor plant using drake built in quadrotor plant class
# this is a System, not a MultiBodyPlant
quadrotor_plant = QuadrotorPlant()
# quadrotor_context = quadrotor_plant.CreateDefaultContext()

quadrotor_plant = builder.AddSystem(quadrotor_plant)


mpc_controller = MpcController(quadrotor_plant, initial_state, final_state, time_horizon, num_time_samples, thrust_limit, obstacles)
mpc_controller = builder.AddSystem(mpc_controller)


# connect the MPC controller to the quadrotor
builder.Connect(mpc_controller.get_output_port(0), quadrotor_plant.get_input_port(0))
builder.Connect(quadrotor_plant.get_output_port(0), mpc_controller.get_input_port(0))

# quad_context = quadrotor_plant.CreateDefaultContext()
# print(quadrotor_plant.get_input_port(0).HasValue(quad_context))


# Set up visualization in MeshCat
QuadrotorGeometry.AddToBuilder(builder, quadrotor_plant.get_output_port(0), scene_graph)
meshcat.Delete()
meshcat.ResetRenderMode()
meshcat.SetProperty('/Background','visible',False)
visualizer = MeshcatVisualizerCpp.AddToBuilder(builder, scene_graph, meshcat)
# end setup for visualization

################# Run Simulation ####################
#Set up a simulator to run this diagram
diagram = builder.Build()

quad_context = quadrotor_plant.CreateDefaultContext()
print(quadrotor_plant.get_input_port(0).HasValue(quad_context))



simulator = Simulator(diagram)
sim_context = simulator.get_mutable_context()
sim_context.SetContinuousState(initial_state)

# pass sim context into MpC controller to be used for linearization of dynamics
mpc_controller.set_sim_context(sim_context)
quadrotor_context = quadrotor_plant.GetMyMutableContextFromRoot(sim_context)

# quadrotor_plant.get_input_port(0).FixValue(quadrotor_context, [10.,10.,10.,10.])
end_time = 10.0
simulator.set_target_realtime_rate(1.0)
meshcat.AddButton('Stop Simulation')
while simulator.get_context().get_time() < end_time:

    simulator.AdvanceTo(sim_context.get_time() + 0.1)

meshcat.DeleteAddedControls()
```

When I run this code I get the following runtime error:

RuntimeError: InputPort::Eval(): required InputPort[0] (propellor_force) of System ::_::drake/examples/quadrotor/QuadrotorPlant@00000000058fa1e0 (QuadrotorPlant) is not connected

However, I have clearly connected it.

To get around this, I have also tried passing the mutable context to the Linearize() method using:

```
quadrotor_context = quadrotor_plant.GetMyMutableContextFromRoot(sim_context)
```

However, when I do this I run into a different error:

SystemExit: Failure at bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tools/install/libdrake/_virtual_includes/drake_shared_library/drake/systems/framework/vector_system.h:290 in DoCalcVectorOutput(): condition 'output->size() == 0' failed.

I believe this error is due to the fact that using the mutable context creates a scenario of infinite recursion, because Linearize() calls DoCalcVectorOutput for the MpcController, which in turn calls Linearize()...

It seems like neither of these approaches is correct. What is the best approach to linearizing the dynamics of an external plant inside of the DoCalcVectorOutput() method of a controller in Drake?

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis of the error is correct.  The `quadrotor_context` that you have in the `MpcController` does not have the input port connected, which is why you get the error when you call `Linearize`. You need to set or connect the input port inside that method in order to specify which input you are linearizing around.

One solution would be to use something like `self.quadrotor_plant.get_input_port().FixValue(quadrotor_context, u0)` in your MpcController `DoCalcVectorOutput` method.